# What approach to follow to compress several integer/float features into one feature for ML modeling?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am not sure which way to go when it comes to compressing a high-dimensional data set (i.e. anywhere from 5-n features) into 1 feature. For example, I have:

```
#refreshes_invoked | #pop_ups_shown | #recommendations_loaded | Y-variable
10                 | 3              | 3
13                 | 4              | 13
```

How can I create something like this?

```
compressed_feature| Y-variable
something         |         
something         |
```

I am trying to use this for ML modeling but I am not sure if where to go. I would like to be able to dissect "something" later for reference so I can "something" for user 1 means:refreshes_invoked is 3 etc.

I looked into integer embedding but that is not a thing. Please advise.

Comment: are you looking for dimensionality reduction? like PCA?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia is there a way to reverse it for interpretability?

Comment: with PCA you have a reconstruction that minimizes the MSE...

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info